# How to move larger values close to matrix diagonal in a correlation matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation

I have a correlation matrix X of five elements(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5)

```
      C1    C2    C3     C4   C5  

 C1    *     1     0     1     0
 C2    1     *     0     0     1
 C3    0     0     *     1     1
 C4    1     0     1     *     0
 C5    0     1     1     0     *
```

I want to use MatLab to move as many as non-zero cells close to diagonal, while keep the diagonal cells are "*".

For example, you may notice that the columns and rows is shifting in the following matrix, while the diagonal cells are "*".

```
      C1    C4    C2     C5   C3  

 C1    *     1     1     0     0
 C4    1     *     0     0     1
 C2    1     0     *     1     0
 C5    0     0     1     *     1
 C3    0     1     0     1     *
```

Because I want to do clustering, so I want as many as non-zero cells get close to diagonal after shifting. It's an NP-hard problem.

Anyone know what functions in MatLab can realize this?

Comment: What do you mean "move close to diagonal"? What would be the desired result for the given example? Also, is there a specific order that you wish to maintain?

Comment: Hi Eitan, for example, now this correlation matrix indicates the dependencies between C1,C2,C3,C4,C5. The diagonal elements is A11, A22, A33, A44, A55, which are equal to "*". After move the non-zero cells close to diagonal, I want to keep A11-A55 in the diagonal of the new matrix.

Comment: So you just want to extract the diagonal?

Comment: Hi Eitan, I saw someone wrote:"diagonalization is obtained by minimizing a cost function which delineates the distance of the entries from the diagonal. Diagonalization correponds to finding the optimal permutation of the entities that minimizes a cost function." But what's the cost function?

Comment: Sorry, it is impossible to explain a sentence without the context. If you cannot explain what you want to achieve, your question cannot be answered properly.

Comment: Sorry, not that easy. I want to generate a new matrix in which the diagonal is A11, A22, A33, A44, A55. But not in this order, maybe like A22, A55, A44, A33, A11. it's just an example.

Comment: Hi Eitan, I edit the question.

Comment: But what is the criterion for shifting columns? How is the resulting matrix better than the original?

Comment: Hi Eitan, In order to keep "*" in diagonal, when the column is shifting, the row is shifting too. Because I want to do clustering, so the closer the non-zero cells to diagonal, the better the result is.

Comment: Do you have any specific criterion for "closer" and "better"?

Comment: closer means the distance to diagonal. For example, in the first matrix, the position of A54 is closer than the position of A52. We get the sum of distance between the diagonal and non-zero cell. The less the sum is, the better the result is.

Comment: What is the distance of A54 to the diagonal? Can you give a number? What is the general formula for that?

Comment: The formula should be in some paper I think. The idea is to implement this criteria (i.e. function matrix -> how_good_it_is), implement a permutation stuff (permutation index -> matrix) and feed it to some optimizer. It is an integer task, so genetic algorithms would perform well. But it is hard to do without criteria.

Comment: Hi EitanT, there is no formula, it's just my idea. Hi Dmitry, I did read this on a paper. I feel it's really interesting. But, I am new to this, can you give me an example? how to set the criteria?

Comment: @user2159011 Did you review my answer?

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is probably the [reverse Cuthill-McKee algorithm (RCM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthill%E2%80%93McKee_algorithm), which pretty much does what you want: for a given matrix it finds a permutation that tends to have its non-zero elements closer to the diagonal. There's a built-in function [`symrcm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/symrcm.html) in MATLAB that does just that.

So assuming that `X` is your matrix, you can do the following:

```
p = symrcm(X);
Xnew = X(p, p);
```

`Xnew` is the new reordered matrix, and `p` is the new row/column order.

#### Example

Let's create a matrix first:

```
X = [10 0 0 7 0; 3 20 0 0 11; 0 0 30 0 29; 12 7 0 40 0; 0 33 0 0 50]
```

Now let's reorder it:

```
p = symrcm(X);
Xnew = X(p, p)
```

The result is:

```
Xnew =    
    40    12     7     0     0
     7    10     0     0     0
     0     3    20    11     0
     0     0    33    50     0
     0     0     0    29    30
```

Seems right.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [1 0  0 1 0;
     0 1  0 0 1;
     0 0  1 0 1;
     1 1  0 1 0;
     0 1  0 0 1]; 
N = length(A);
switched = false;

%%
% Calculate initial Global Energy
disp(A);
global_energy = 0;
for l = 1:N
    for m = 1:N
        if(A(l,m))
            global_energy = global_energy + (l-m)^2/2;
        end
    end
end
disp(global_energy); 

counter = 0;
counter_cutoff = 10000000000;
while(true)
    switched = false;
    counter = counter + 1;
    for i = 1:N
        for j = i+1:N        
            current_metric = 0; % Calculate metric of row i and j with columns i and j
            permuted_metric = 0; % Calculate metric if they were permuted        
            % Row i
            for k = 1:N
                if(k ~= i && k ~= j && A(i,k))
                    current_metric = current_metric + (i-k)^2/2;
                    permuted_metric = permuted_metric + (j-k)^2/2;
                end
            end
            % Row j
            for k = 1:N
                if(k ~= i && k ~= j && A(j,k))
                    current_metric = current_metric + (j-k)^2/2;
                    permuted_metric = permuted_metric + (i-k)^2/2;
                end
            end
            % Col i
            for k = 1:N
                if(k ~= i && k ~= j && A(k,i))
                    current_metric = current_metric + (i-k)^2/2;
                    permuted_metric = permuted_metric + (j-k)^2/2;
                end
            end
            % Col j 
            for k = 1:N
                if(k ~= i && k ~= j && A(k,j))
                    current_metric = current_metric + (j-k)^2/2;
                    permuted_metric = permuted_metric + (i-k)^2/2;
                end
            end

            % If permuted metric is less, swap columns and rows - set switched to true 
            if(permuted_metric < current_metric)
                switched = true; % there was at least one switch
                % Now switch rows and columns
                % Switch columns first
                A(:,[i j]) = A(:,[j i]);
                % Now switch rows
                A([i j],:) = A([j i],:);
            end
        end
    end
    if(~switched || counter > counter_cutoff)
        % All permutations did not lead to a switching of rows and columns
        break;
    end
end

% Calculate final Global Energy
disp(A);
global_energy = 0;
for l = 1:N
    for m = 1:N
        if(A(l,m))
            global_energy = global_energy + (l-m)^2/2;
        end
    end
end
disp(global_energy);
```

Terminal:

```
 1     0     0     1     0
 0     1     0     0     1
 0     0     1     0     1
 1     1     0     1     0
 0     1     0     0     1

22

 1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     1     0     0
 0     0     1     1     0
 0     0     1     1     0
 0     0     0     1     1

 3
```