# maximizing matrix diagonal elements in R

Tags: r, optimization, matrix, correlation

Edit : a related question is [How to move larger values close to matrix diagonal in a correlation matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351835/how-to-move-larger-values-close-to-matrix-diagonal-in-a-correlation-matrix) This question is about achieving same but in R

Given a matrix (or table in R )

```
m <- matrix(c(5,25,8,4,2,10,20,3,1),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(m) <- c("L","M","H")
rownames(m) <- c("A","B","C")
tax <- as.table(m)
tax
   L  M  H
A  5 25  8
B  4  2 10
C 20  3  1
```

I want to rearrange the matrix such that the diagonal elements are maximum.

```
   H  L  M
B 10  4  2
C  1 20  3
A  8  5 25
```

Is there any easy to use function in R ?

Comment: In general it is impossible to maximize more than one thing simultaneously.  This means your objective is ill-defined: you will need to decide more precise *what single number* gets maximized.  Once you clear that up, please repost your question on [SO], where it might be on topic.

Comment: I just want to rearrange the rows and columns so that maximum values are at the diagonal. What is "unclear" here?

Comment: You have just clarified what was originally an ill-posed programming question.  Now that it is apparent what you want to do, it will likely be considered on-topic on [SO].

Comment: Does the order of diagonal elements matter?

Comment: I found a same question but for Matlab http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351835/how-to-move-larger-values-close-to-matrix-diagonal-in-a-correlation-matrix  I am looking for same but in R !!!

Answer (score 2):

```
matrix.sort <- function(matrix) {

    if (nrow(matrix) != ncol(matrix)) stop("Not diagonal")
    if(is.null(rownames(matrix))) rownames(matrix) <- 1:nrow(matrix)

    row.max <- apply(matrix,1,which.max)
    if(all(table(row.max) != 1)) stop("Ties cannot be resolved")

    matrix[names(sort(row.max)),]
}
```

Comment: You could replace `apply(matrix, 1, which.max)` with `setNames(max.col(matrix), rownames(matrix))` to gain efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Rohit Arora's solution is doing exactly what you want because it will be led by the maximum value of the preceding row. As a result, it's not in fact maximising the diagonal in a optimisation sense.

I found this answer to a similar question elsewhere and I thought it might be useful:

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/reordering-of-matrix-rows-to-maximize-the-sum-of-the-diagonal-tt2062867.html#a2065679

```
pMatrix.min <- function(A, B) { 
#finds the permutation P of A such that ||PA - B|| is minimum in Frobenius norm 
# Uses the linear-sum assignment problem (LSAP) solver in the "clue" package 

# Returns P%*%A and the permutation vector `pvec' such that 
# A[pvec, ] is the permutation of A closest to B 
    n <- nrow(A) 
    D <- matrix(NA, n, n) 
    for (i in 1:n) { 
        for (j in 1:n) { 
        D[j, i] <- (sum((B[j, ] - A[i, ])^2)) 
        }
    } 
    vec <- c(solve_LSAP(D)) 
    list(A=A[vec,], pvec=vec) 
} 

require(clue)  # need this package to solve the LSAP 

#An example
A <- matrix(sample(1:25, size=25, rep=FALSE),  5,  5) 

B <- diag(1, nrow(A)) # this choice of B maximizes the trace of permuted A 

X <- pMatrix.min(A,B) 

A  # original square matrix 

X$A  # permuted A such that its trace is maximum among all permutations
```

It uses the Hungarian method to optimise the reordering of the matrix A to the target matrix B.

NB This is my first post so I don't have the reputation to comment on the previous answer, but I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a similar problem and wrote a simple function to maximize the sum of the elements in the diagonal of a square matrix. It does not check whether the matrix is squared (it could be easily implemented). Also, be careful with very large matrices since the number of permutations is the factorial of the number of columns.

```
maxDiag <- function(x) {
  n <- ncol(x)
  per <- gtools::permutations(n,n)
  d <- apply(per,1,function(y) sum(diag(x[,y])))
  return(x[,per[which.max(d),]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `order` + `which.max` to rearrange the rows and columns like below

```
> m[order(apply(m, 2, which.max)), order(apply(m, 1, which.max))]
   H  L  M
B 10  4  2
C  1 20  3
A  8  5 25
```