# Sort Collection based on similarity

Tags: java, collections, optaplanner

I have calculated a matrix containing boolean values between people indicating if they share a certain property. I would like to order the rows (and use this ordering to order the columns as well) of this matrix based on the similarities between people. So multiple people that display a similar "sharing-profile" should be ordered together. For example, the properties between 6 people:

```
 name P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6
 P1   x  x
 P2   x  x
 P3         x  x  x    
 P4         x  x  x  
 P5         x  x  x
 P6            x  x  x
```

In the example P1 and P2 share the properties and are therefore ordered together. The same holds for P3, P4 and P5. Note that the properties don't have to be identical. For instance, P6 is most similar to P3/P4/P5 so that's why it's close to that cluster.

I've tried to come up with a specific Java Comparator but that usually works with return values -1 0 and 1 and in my case I only have a single similarity score. Unfortunately, it needs to be in Java as this is the main lanuage for the whole project...

Anywone any idea how to sort the matrix based on the similarity scores?

[edit]
I've added the **optaplanner** tag which I found when I was googling the problem based on a comment. It seems to applicable to my problem, perhaps someone with knowledge of **optaplanner** can confirm that it is a relevant tool for my problem?

Comment: "I've tried to come up with a specific Java Comparator but that usually works with return values -1 0 and 1 and in my case I only have a single similarity score." - what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean: "Collections.Sort() work:
Internally the Sort method does call Compare method of the classes it is sorting. To compare two elements, it asks “Which is greater?” Compare method returns -1, 0 or 1 to say if it is less than, equal, or greater to the other. It uses this result to then determine if they should be swapped for its sort." and my data does not allow a -1 0 or 1 to be created.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really "sort" here: what you're actually doing is *grouping*.

Assuming you have some method which returns the property on which they should be grouped, you can group the elements together into a map, keyed by that property:

```
Function<Person, SomeType> groupingFn = ... // SomeType is the type of the property on which to group.
Map<SomeType, List<Person>> = people.stream().collect(groupingBy(groupingFn));
```

You can then flatten this back into a list, where the elements are grouped together:

```
List<Person> grouped =
    people.values().stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But wouldn't this grouping only allow for the grouping of data that have an identical sharing profile? What about the case in which 2 people share 80 attributes but one is different. Still very similar and they should be sorted/grouped together. Would the grouping method still allows this?

Comment: "What about the case in which 2 people share 80 attributes but one is different." That's up to you. This method works if you can partition your people into equivalence classes (which is what you've shown in your question); if you want things that are not equivalent but merely similar, you need to decide whether e.g. 2 people with 1 attribute differing by 2*X are more or less similar than 2 people with 2 attributes differing by X.

Comment: You're right, I didn't put in an example that is not identical to the others. I've added P6 to be clearer.

Comment: That makes the problem a lot harder. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351835/how-to-move-larger-values-close-to-matrix-diagonal-in-a-correlation-matrix

Comment: Thanks Andy, that at least makes me feel less stupid about not coming up with a solution myself :-). I am now looking into http://www.optaplanner.org/ which I discovered after searching for the Minimum Bandwidth Problem.